# Add column to dataframe according to reference

Tags: r, dataframe

I have got two dataframes with different types of data (data1-3). Both concern the same participants ("person1" etc).
`df1` contains the column `group`. I would like to add this column to `df2`, according to the column `ID` (e.g., `person3` will always belong to `group1`). Note that the number of rows (= unique observations) per `person` is not equal in the two dataframes.

This is my input:

```
ID <- c("person1", "person1", "person2", "person3", "person3", "person3", "person4")
data1 <- c(1:7)
data2 <- c(6:12)
group <- c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group2")
df1 <- data.frame(ID, data1, data2, group)

ID <- c("person1", "person2", "person2", "person3", "person3", "person4", "person4")
data3 <- c(7:13)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, data3)

> df1
       ID data1 data2  group
1 person1     1     6 group1
2 person1     2     7 group1
3 person2     3     8 group2
4 person3     4     9 group1
5 person3     5    10 group1
6 person3     6    11 group1
7 person4     7    12 group2

> df2
       ID data3
1 person1     7
2 person2     8
3 person2     9
4 person3    10
5 person3    11
6 person4    12
7 person4    13
```

This is the desired output:

```
ID <- c("person1", "person2", "person2", "person3", "person3", "person4", "person4")
data3 <- c(7:13)
group <- c("group1", "group2", "group2", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2")
df2final <- data.frame(ID, data3, group)

> df2final
       ID data3  group
1 person1     7 group1
2 person2     8 group2
3 person2     9 group2
4 person3    10 group1
5 person3    11 group1
6 person4    12 group2
7 person4    13 group2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `merge` + `unique`

```
> merge(df2, unique(df1[c("ID","group")]))
       ID data3  group
1 person1     7 group1
2 person2     8 group2
3 person2     9 group2
4 person3    10 group1
5 person3    11 group1
6 person4    12 group2
7 person4    13 group2
```